# What is the difference between separation, quitting and layoffs?

Tags: employment, legal-terms, definition

Is separation considered to be a measure of layoffs and quitting from firm's perspective?

Comment: This question might be better suited for [law.se]. Also, the exact details of legal code of the country/state probably matter, so these details should be included in your question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about English; the terms are defined by usage, not by law.

Comment: Try https://www.merriam-webster.com/

Comment: Employment law is a form of law. I think that the OP should probably specify s jurisdiction, though, because every country's employment laws are different.

Comment: legal terminology is on-topic here

Comment: I tend to agree with @DavidSiegel that there's an on-topic question in here, but it might need some editing to get there.  Not voting to close, especially because rejected migrations are a huge mess.

Comment: If there is an on-topic question here, it is not currently written in the post. The meaning of words can sometimes be defined in law, and employment law is no different. But in the absence of any indication that the terms **are** legally defined for a particular jurisdiction (and the only answer so far has not given any sign of it either, merely describing the use of words in English)  it is not a question of legal terminology or law. Migration mess or not, that's how the system is.

Comment: in any case, the question is not asked in a way that makes it answerable here: there is nothing to hinge an answer on but terms that are defined vastly different in different jurisdictions!

Comment: I agree that terms may be defined differently in different jurisdictions but I would be surprised if the difference is "vast". We all know in general terms what a layoff is - i.e. telling workers not to come into work for the moment because of lack of work. I think that the OP should first be encouraged to add a jurisdiction before the question is pre-emptively closed.

Answer (score 1):

- "***Separation***" is a generic term indicating that the person no longer works at the firm, or more often the process by which the person's employment ends. It can refer to a resignation, a retirement, or a layoff or a discharge.
- A "***layoff***" is an event where one or more workers have their employment ended by the company, because there is no work of the type that they had been doing available. It most often is used of multiple employees at the same time. It may imply that the firm will offer the former employees a chance to return to work if conditions change. It implies that individual fault was not the primary reason for the end of employment.  However, the word is sometimes used when the employee was at fault, as a way to soften the description. In some industries, there are legal consequences to a layoff that do not apply to other kinds of termination of employment, generally additional benefits or protections for employees who have been laid off.
- A "***resignation***" (or less formally "quitting" ) is a voluntary choice by the employee to leave a job, for any reason.
- "***Retirement***" is a special sense of resignation. It implies that the employee has left the job because s/he is at the end of a career, and usually has been in that job for multiple years. Unless it is a "mandatory retirement" it is at the decision of the employee.
- The terms "***termination***", "***discharge***", and "***firing***" all mean that the employer has decided to end the employment for some individual reason, often something judged to be the fault of the employee.

Comment: At least in Australia, termination is a neutral term akin to separation (which isn’t used here).

Comment: In the united Kingdom *separation* is not used but *severance* is sometimes used particularly in the phrase *severance pay*. In the UK *termination* is a neutral word to lawyers but in popular usage tends to mean *fired*

Comment: A retirement may not be a separation, if the employer continues to provide benefits such as an ERISA compliant pension, or health insurance, or (in the example of my grandfather) an on-campus professor emeritus office.